# mvc WebSecurity.CurrentUserName empty and CurrentUserID -1 after user logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webmatrix

Below is the code used to login

```
WebSecurity.Login("abc", "123", true);//return true
return RedirectToAction("afterLogin", @"afterLogin");
```

After loggin in, I checked the user's id to see if it's **-1** by running the below line:

```
WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
```

But why whenever I called this, the return value always -1 and `CurrentUserName` is empty?

edited:

An additional question:

Does the `WebSecurity` have something like timeout so that the user idle for a specific period and will logged out automatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC 4 SimpleMembership - Why WebSecurity.CurrentUserId -1 after login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850861/mvc-4-simplemembership-why-websecurity-currentuserid-1-after-login)

Comment: I've tried the solution before on that link, I've redirected to another page, but the result was still the same.

Comment: You should split this into 2 different questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the default expiration is when the browser session ends. It might be that cookies are not enabled and that's why it is returning -1 cookies need to be enabled.

Comment: I've checked the developer tools and found there's a cookie called "AUTH" and has value in it..

Comment: Quite strange I have no idea what's going on then. You might want to debug your website in Visual Studio.

Comment: Do I need to "Redirect" to another page for the cookie to take effect? or can I have an example about how to use the WebSecurity.CurrentUserName function.?

Comment: Hi, there is a ref for the WebSecurity class available here: http://www.thecodingguys.net/reference/asp/websecurity-class

Comment: Thanks, let me take a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

Check your webconfig, you have to enable forms authentication:

Add following snippet inside

```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="3600" />
    </authentication>
```

Comment out if it is in your webconfig:

```
<!--<modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>-->
```

Now you can check

WebSecurity.CurrentUserName, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId and , WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated flags;

Also add this class in app_start

```
public static class AuthConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterAuth()
        {
 }
}
```

and call this in AppStart in Global.asax.cs

```
AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
```